# try initialize project in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to start a project with react and want first just to show "Hello World" in the index.js.
I try to render a div from  the index.js file with "Hello World" to the div calls 'root' in my index.html

**index.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <meta name="description" content="Majordojo smart containers" />
  <link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json" />
  <!-- <script src="/__/firebase/7.14.5/firebase-app.js"></script> -->
  <!-- <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="/__/firebase/7.14.5/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
  <script src="/__/firebase/7.14.5/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="/__/firebase/7.14.5/firebase-firestore.js"></script> -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../src/index.js"></script>

  
    <title>Majordomo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
import '../src/index.css';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

alert("hi");
ReactDOM.render(<div>Hello World</div>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

When I do npm start I get a blank page even without the alert, can someone please
What I'm missing?

Comment: Can you share your whole code?

Comment: if you mean the whole code of index.js so it's only a few imports

Comment: Yes , if you can share the index.js , then maybe I can help.

Comment: this is the whole code in index.js:

`import '../src/index.css'; `

`import React from 'react';`

`import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';`

`alert("hi")`

`ReactDOM.render(<div>Hello World</div>, document.getElementById('root'));`

Comment: have you checked for any error in your console?

Comment: I run it from visual studio code and see only warnings about unused variables